# Ionic build is failed

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

When I try to build ionic app i throw this error:

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

I was trying to change buildToolsVersion and compileSdkVersion but it's not working.

Comment: Could you let me know which file to change comileSdkVersion?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I resolved my problem, i type `ionic cordova resources`

Answer (score -1):

i have same issue i use **cordova-android-support-gradle-release plugin** to fix this issue you can try this.

link:https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-android-support-gradle-release

Comment: I try this, but it's not working. What version of cordova are you using?